# To what extent is scapegoating correlated with personality?

Tags: social-psychology, personality, big-five

The Wikipedia [article on scapegoating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoating) is rather thin on correlates, but has plenty of "pure" theories as to what causes scapegoating, not backed by much if any evidence, even correlational.

So what is known about the correlates of this behavior, and for starters personality, e.g. Big Five?

(Edit: Initially, I asked about other correlates too, but that's probably too broad for just one question.)

Comment: I feel this question is very broad. There are studies into possible scapegoating behaviour within companies in relation to organization performance issues etc. There are studies on scapegoating within gender prejudice, immigrant scapegoating studies, familial scapegoating studies, studies on scapegoating within sport .... the list goes on. Is there a particular social area of scapegoating you are wanting to look at?

Comment: @ChrisRogers: Yeah, I should probably split it in two or there separate q (pers / cross-cult/ combo [multi-factor] studies) since we have no q here about any of that. I'm a bit busy ATM though... Later today.

Comment: I think that even with your edit, your question is still very broad. (See my previous comment). What area of scapegoating are you wanting to examine?

Comment: @ChrisRogers: is there a reason to think personality correlates for scapegoating in sport would be different from personality correlates for scapegoating in immigrant studies?